# Linq C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, group-by

I try to convert the following linq code from c# to vb.net.

```
var groupedPhotos = from photo in photos
                    orderby photo.TimeStamp
                    group photo by photo.TimeStamp.ToString("y") into photosByMonth
                    select new KeyedList<string, Photo>(photosByMonth);
```

When i convert as following, i get an error saying "Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments". Where i have to change?

```
 Dim groupedPhotos = From photo In photos
                     Order By photo.TimeStamp
                     Group photo By photo.TimeStamp.ToString("y") Into Group 
                     Select New KeyedList(Of String, Photo)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q&A sites generally require a question.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples | Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that one:

```
Dim groupedPhotos = From photo In photos
                    Order By photo.TimeStamp
                    Group photo By Key = photo.TimeStamp.ToString("y") Into g = Group 
                    Select New KeyedList(Of String, Photo)(g)
```